# Laravel Guzzlehttp cURL error 56: SSLRead() return error -9806 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle6

We have website that consumes API using `Oauth 1.0`. The website has been working fine till a few days ago. Our server from which we consume the apis moved to a new hosting service provider. Since then we are getting the error message

> cURL error 56: SSLRead() return error -9806 (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

We have tried disabling ssl verification, but that did not seem to work either. It seems that we are not able to hit the server at all. The service provider tells us there is no record of our program reaching their server at all.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

.....

$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 
 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5', 
 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate', 
 'Connection: keep-alive', 
];

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => self::getBaseUrl().'/ETCAPICP/api/', 'headers' => $headers]);
```

Actual Result:

> message: "cURL error 56: SSLRead() return error -9806 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"

What is expected is that, the program should be able to successfully complete the handshake and be able to consume the APIs

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whenever Guzzle is trying to make a curl connection, it prepares and submits the request with the information that is available to it. Where it does not have any information it simply sets that parameter to null.

The header value for "User-Agent" was null in the request, and that seemed to be the culprit. I had to add "User-Agent" in the header request, and everything now works fine.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

.....

$headers = [
 'User-Agent' => 'Testing 1.0'
];

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => self::getBaseUrl().'/ETCAPICP/api/', 'headers' => $headers]);
```

Hope this helps for any one else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it can mean some parameters values are empty or null.